# Is "wisdom" natural in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, idiomatic-language

***Thank you for your kindness, your generosity, and your wisdom.***

Can I say this in formal speech to an old guy who have taken good care of me and taught me a lot?

Is "wisdom" natural to use or is it overly formal. Is it just out of place?

Comment: Wisdom isn't something that you can thank someone for any more than their age or how they walk, but you can thank them for their **guidance**. He did not give you wisdom, but the *benefit* of his wisdom.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is fine if this is what you appreciate in him. However, your question is a bit vague. You mention that you are looking for formal speech, but then you are worried you might be too formal. So I assume your relationship with the "old guy" is not highly formal.

I would formulate your sentence like this:

> ***I am grateful*** (it is a bit more formal than just *Thank you*) ***for your
> kindness, generosity and wisdom.***

Answer (score 1):

That sounds really natural and solid. Wisdom is a common everyday word, often contrasted with knowledge. Some answers here are getting pretty technical in details, but I think your sentence is straightforward and good just how it is.